# Add Helm chart dependencies with GitLab Auto DevOps

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm, cicd, gitlab-autodevops

I'd like to deploy additional services (e.g. a certain kind of database) with my (review) application when using GitLab Auto DevOps. [Customizing Auto DevOps/Custom Helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#custom-helm-chart) suggests to create a `./chart` directory and put the full chart there.

Does that mean I have to copy the complete [default chart](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/-/tree/master/assets/auto-deploy-app) to my repository, only to add a `./chart/requirements.yaml` file? Is there a possibility to somehow "merge" the charts? I don't need to fully replace the default chart with a custom chart, I only need to add requirements (and override a few settings in `./chart/values.yaml`; which can already be done with [Customize Helm chart values](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#customize-helm-chart-values)).

What's the canonical way to add a requirement to the default chart?

1. Copy the complete default chart and adapt? (feels like overkill and needs to be kept in sync manually)
2. Override the deployment CI pipeline job to download the default chart and merge it with the custom requirements?
3. Find a way similar to customizing Helm chart values – does it exist?
4. Adding another CI pipeline job to deploy the requirement separately?